# Ubuntu 14.4 Logs out user when hitting Super key

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I was using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to run an `ls` redirected to a file. Later I tried it again and was logged out. After logging back in I tried it again, same thing.

Now whenever I tap the Super key or click on the search icon in the Dash, I get logged out. I have tried googling the problem, but haven't found any reference to the exact issue. I found one article that suggested doing a reinstall of ubuntu-desktop and unity. I tried an update then the reinstall and still get logged out. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this and how it may have started?

I'm not a complete noob, but I don't consider myself any where near proficient. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you update & reinstall? Have u tried reseting unity with ubutu tweek?

Comment: I used tty to do the reinstall from another post on Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Install and run unity-reapir using ubutu tweak tool. You can install and run this in tty mode by following the below process.

**First make sure everything is ok.**

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Next get updates for packages

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Getting unity-reset:** Install unity-reset from Link If you can -> [Install unity-reset](https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb)

**Installing unity-reset in tty mode:**

First add the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily && sudo apt-get update
```

Install Ubutu tweak tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To reset tweak tool:

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

Then type:

```
$ unity-reset
```

You may need to reboot.

**How to Reinstall unity:**
After ruining updates

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Next Install Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-terminal && sudo apt-get update
```

Then reboot.

**Last option** install new desktop from tty this option installs Gnome Desktop

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: I tried everything except the LAST OPTION and still have the same issue. When this happened I was running an _ls_  command from the desktop and piping it to a file. I used the 'F2' key to open the command window.

Comment: BTW after running 'unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity' 'unity-reset' came back as **command not found**.